# Cannot Assign Value Of Type 'CGColor' To UIColor

Tags: swift4, xcode9

I want to change the default blue of the back button. I have created my own color, which works completely fine with my text fields. Whenever I try to use this code to change the back button with my custom color, it doesn't work and I get the error. Below is my code:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = myColor.cgColor
```

I'm not sure if it has to do with anything, but when I connected my VC to my navigation controller, it automatically had the back button appear in my VC. However, it doesn't show a navigation bar or navigation item in the [side panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwghZ.png).

I also tried searching StackOverflow- it seems I can only find problems and solutions for 'UIColor to CGColor', not 'CGColor to UIColor'. These solutions don't work for me. Thanks!

Comment: What is the data type of `myColor`?

Comment: @PhillipMills let myColor = UIColor(red: 0.61, green: 0.31, blue: 0.89, alpha: 1.0)

Comment: @DeborahP., try my answer. you already have UIColor, you dont need to convert it to CGColor and then get UIColor back again.

Comment: `tintColor` expects `UIColor`. Why do you pass `CGColor`? Instead of searching SO use Quick Help to check the types.

Comment: Since it's already a `UIColor` there doesn't seem to be anything extra to do.

Comment: It's strange because Xcode requires me to add the myColor.cgColor with my text fields. What's the difference for this?

Comment: @DeborahP., layers require CGColors where as in other places you can use UIColors directly.

Comment: @adev got it, thank you! Will mark your answer correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = myColor`

Comment: Didn't know layers require CGColors and other items can use UIColor directly. Thanks!